# Nothing is printed out from the command line using Gimp

Tags: python, cmd, printing, arguments, gimp

It says 'batch command executed successfully' but nothing is printed out on the command line. Am I missing something? I am using Windows.

`gimp-console-2.10.exe -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import test; test.main(\"print this out\")"`

The filename is `test.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gimpfu import *

def main(mystring):
    print(mystring)
```

Comment: I am not sure how escape character \ works on windows. try passing a number instead of a `str` to `main`. Or try passing just `print(1)` as the `-b` argument

Answer (score 0):

You can't print to the console on Windows - it gets buffered and then hangs when the buffer is full.

See here for alternatives: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows